# Why doesn't this simple subquery work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a simple correlated sub query that deletes all records for the selected members except the latest one.

```
DELETE FROM table1  p
WHERE member_id IN (1, 2,3)
AND create_dttm < (SELECT MAX(create_dttm) 
                   FROM table1   
                   WHERE  member_id = p.member_id)
```

But I get an error message

> Incorrect syntax near 'p'.

I can easily write 3 queries to get the work done. But was curious to know what is going wrong here ? Could you please enlighten me how to write this query correctly ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
DELETE p
FROM table1  p
WHERE member_id IN (1, 2,3)
AND create_dttm < (SELECT MAX(create_dttm) 
                   FROM table1   
                   WHERE  member_id = p.member_id)
```

Comment: Thanks John.. But this didn't work..Same error "Incorrect syntax near 'p'."

Comment: @Ananth: There's *absolutely* no syntax error in this answer, it worked for me perfectly well. You must have missed something when applying it to your real table.

Comment: @Andiry , John. Query works just fine..It was my bad..Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ John. accepted..It will be really gr8 if u cud explain why this query worked and mine didnt

Comment: Thx. Your original syntax works for a SELECT statement, but when deleting from a table with an alias, you need to separately associate the alias with DELETE FROM.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could alias the table *in the subquery* and reference the outer instance's `member_id` by the table's real name:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE WHERE member_id IN (1, 2,3)
AND create_dttm < (SELECT MAX(create_dttm) 
                   FROM table1 p
                   WHERE  table1.member_id = p.member_id)
```

In SQL Server, when you assign an alias to a table, you can no longer reference that table by its original name in the same statement. So, prefixing columns with `table1.` in the subquery, you would certainly be referencing the outer table.

Comment: +1 This is the most logical way: targeting the `DELETE` at the range variable ('alias') `p` in theory should leave the base table unaffected., clearly not the intention.

Comment: Thanks. I think aliasing the outer table make sense too, at least when the name is particularly long (and one is particularly lazy) :)

Answer (score 1):

And use some Alias for the tables:

```
DELETE FROM table1 p
WHERE p.member_id IN (1, 2,3)
AND p.create_dttm < (SELECT MAX(p1.create_dttm) 
                   FROM table1 p1 
                   WHERE p1.member_id = p.member_id)
```

Comment: Not going to work - The error occurs because you can't have an alias on the DELETE FROM table

Comment: Sure, you are correct! I remember, i had such a problem a long time ago ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
DELETE p FROM table1 p
WHERE member_id IN (1, 2,3)
AND create_dttm < (SELECT MAX(create_dttm) 
                   FROM table1   
                   WHERE  member_id = p.member_id)
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't, but your suggestion is a complete replica of @John Dewey's.